# Alternative choice for find function in Julia to improve the speed

Tags: julia

I have a code that I use find function inside a loop which lower the efficiency I guess. I aim to improve the speed of the code and I am trying to replace each part with a faster version. In my code I need to check if variable A, (which takes different values in each iteration) has elements equal to 2.

```
C = in.(A, 2)

N = findall(x->x==0, C)

B = findall(x->x!=0, C)

TF = isempty(B)
```

Comment: You will likely get better success by posting more code. Optimization generally comes from more than speeding up a single slow line.

Comment: perhaps you should search over a sorted list (searchsorted) or a Set. A simplified  MWE is needed.

Comment: Are you trying to find out if `A` contains the value 2? In that case, it's just `TF = 2 in A`